# openssl random pseudo bytes - repeatable?

Tags: php, php-5.3, password-protection

I found this **openssl_random_pseudo_bytes** functions from php.net.

```
function generate_password($length = 24) {

    if(function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes')) {
        $password = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length, $strong));
        if($strong == TRUE)
            return substr($password, 0, $length); //base64 is about 33% longer, so we need to truncate the result
    }

    # fallback to mt_rand if php < 5.3 or no openssl available
    $characters = '0123456789';
    $characters .= 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/+'; 
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters)-1;
    $password = '';

    # select some random characters
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $password .= $characters[mt_rand(0, $charactersLength)];
    }        

    return $password;
}
```

But I want to be sure that whether the value it generates is **repeatable** or not? I am looking for a result which is not repeatable.

I have been told that the value from `mt_rand()` is **not** repeatable? but a random number **should** be repeatable as it self-explained already - mt_**rand**, doesn't it?

**EDIT:**

for instance, I just tested it and it has generated `W8hhkS+ngIl7DxxFDxEx6gSn`. but if will generate the same value again in the future - then it is **repeatable**.

Comment: What do you mean by repeatable

Comment: for instance, it has generated `W8hhkS+ngIl7DxxFDxEx6gSn` and then will generate the same value again in the future - then it is repeatable.

Comment: Well if the output is of fixed length then you will eventually get the same value again, eg if the output is of length 8 and there are 64 possible values then after 64^8 + 1 goes there will be at least one repetition (by the pigeonhole principle).

Comment: thanks, so then I must not fix the length then?

Comment: but we must fix the length in `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` as it says it php.net - `he length of the desired string of bytes. Must be a positive integer. PHP will try to cast this parameter to a non-null integer to use it.`

Answer (score 6):

random_pseudo_bytes is not repeatable. It is true that any output of finite length must eventually repeat, for example if you specify a length of 1 byte, then there is only 256 possible strings, so you *must* get the same string you had before no later than after 256 attempts (and likely quite a bit sooner).

But you're talking *practically* and not *mathemathically*, and have a default length of 24.

Yes, picking random 24-byte strings will *eventually* give you a string that you had before, but that's only true in the mathemathical universe. In the real physical universe, there's 6277101735386680763835789423207666416102355444464034512896 possible such strings, which means that even if you generated billions of passwords this way every second, you'd still not be likely to get the same string twice in a million years.

Answer (score 0):

Any random function, including the one above, is repeatable.
Perhaps you're looking for the PHP function uniqid?

Comment: Any finite-length strength will eventually repeat. But that's true only in the mathemathical sense - in a practical sense, a truly random string of sufficient length will never repeat. (more accurately: is EXTREMELY unlikely to ever repeat)